# Is there any way where we can dynamically change favicon in experience builder salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have a Site with multiple custom URL's with different domain names. Here I have an option to add a Site Favorite Icon- a static resource to show a favicon for the site and site settings. But is there any way i can change favicon dynamically based on the domain URL?
[Site Favorite Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkeec.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by adding a function in the script to update the  and . It initially loads the default but quickly updates it. Not sure if anyone has a better solution?

```
<head>
  <title>Default Title</title>
  <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="{!$Resource.favDefault}" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script>
    function updateTitleAndFavicon() {
      const urlToTitleAndFaviconMap = {
        "www.brand1.com": { title: "Brand 1", favicon: "{!$Resource.favBrand1}" },
        "www.brand2.com": { title: "Brand 2", favicon: "{!$Resource.favBrand2}" },
        "www.brand3.com": { title: "Brand 3", favicon: "{!$Resource.favBrand3}" },
        "www.brand4.com": { title: "Brand 4", favicon: "{!$Resource.favBrand4}" }
      };

      const currentDomain = window.location.hostname;
      const newTitleAndFavicon = urlToTitleAndFaviconMap[currentDomain];

      if (newTitleAndFavicon) {
        document.title = newTitleAndFavicon.title;
        document.getElementById("favicon").href = newTitleAndFavicon.favicon;
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", updateTitleAndFavicon);
  </script>
</head>
```